# symfony 4: An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4, dbal

Working with Doctrine DBAL in Symfony 4 with the following conofiguration (doctrine.yaml):

```
dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: '5.7'
    charset: utf8mb4
    default_table_options:
        charset: utf8mb4
        collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    driver_class: App\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver
```

and .env:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:passwd@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname
```

we are unable to connect to the database via DBAL:

```
$conn = DriverManager::getConnection(Constants::connectionParams,new Configuration());
```

Getting An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver exception. I haven't found documentation about that error in this version in S4.

Comment: Have you enabled php pdo extensions?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you are missing the PDO mysql extension.

Try to install it like below :

If you are running linux with apache2 do the following:

```
apt-get install php-mysql
```

After the above command has finished edit you php.ini file like so :

- Search for **pdo_mysql** extension

It will be something like this

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Change this line to this:

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

And after changing **php.ini** file, restart apache service like this:

```
service apache2 restart
```

PS: **you may need to use sudo**